# Condições em datas no MYSQL saber qual o último registro e o penúltimo

Tags: mysql

Trata-se do seguinte preciso realizar uma consulta no meu banco de dados pela última data de cadastro e onde a featured seja = à 0. Executo desta maneira sem problemas:

```
SQL1 = SELECT id, created, featured FROM roexd_content WHERE created = (SELECT MAX(created) FROM roexd_content WHERE featured=0) ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 1
```

A minha dificuldade esta em buscar o penúltimo registro cadastrado, meu sql para o penúltimo está assim:

```
SQL2 = SELECT id, created, featured FROM roexd_content WHERE created <= (SELECT MAX(created) FROM roexd_content WHERE featured=0) AND id <= (SELECT MAX(id) FROM roexd_content WHERE id <= (SELECT MAX(id)-1 FROM roexd_content WHERE featured=0)) ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 1
```

Obtenho como resposta o seguinte:

> ```
> 1- Último Registro SQL1 / id -> 229 | created -> 2017-09-27 15:14:00 | featured -> 0|    
> 2- Penúltimo Registro SQL2 / id -> 228 | created -> 2017-09-27 12:37:00 | featured -> 0|
> ```

Agora se o registro 229 passar a ter `featured=1`, a visualização é a seguinte:

> ```
> 1- Último Registro SQL1 / id -> 228 | created -> 2017-09-27 12:37:00 | featured -> 0|
> 2- Penúltimo Registro SQL2 / id -> 220 | created -> 2017-09-27 03:09:00 | featured -> 0|
> ```

O problema é se o 228 passar a ter featured=1, tanto na SQL1 e SQL2 o registro retornado é o 220, o certo seria que o 220 fosse o Último registro e o 227 o Penúltimo Registro pela data de cadastro. A tabela abaixo segue a base da minhas informações:

> ```
> +--------------------------------------+
> | id  | created             | featured |
> +-----+---------------------+----------+
> | 201 | 2017-09-14 02:34:00 |    0     |
> | 202 | 2017-09-14 02:40:32 |    0     |
> | 203 | 2017-09-14 02:52:00 |    0     |
> | 204 | 2017-09-14 02:58:00 |    0     |
> | 205 | 2017-09-14 03:15:08 |    0     |
> | 206 | 2017-09-14 16:37:00 |    0     |
> | 207 | 2017-09-20 01:13:00 |    0     |
> | 208 | 2017-09-15 15:36:00 |    0     |
> | 209 | 2017-09-15 15:57:00 |    0     |
> | 210 | 2017-09-19 22:14:00 |    0     |
> | 211 | 2017-09-18 22:19:00 |    0     |
> | 212 | 2017-09-18 22:27:00 |    0     |
> | 213 | 2017-09-18 22:33:00 |    0     |
> | 214 | 2017-09-20 01:46:00 |    0     |
> | 215 | 2017-09-20 02:10:00 |    0     |
> | 216 | 2017-09-21 01:50:00 |    0     |
> | 217 | 2017-09-21 02:01:00 |    0     |
> | 218 | 2017-09-21 02:21:00 |    0     |
> | 219 | 2017-09-22 03:04:00 |    0     |
> | 220 | 2017-09-27 03:09:00 |    0     |
> | 221 | 2017-09-22 03:17:00 |    0     |
> | 222 | 2017-09-22 03:32:00 |    0     |
> | 223 | 2017-09-22 03:43:00 |    0     |
> | 224 | 2017-09-22 11:45:00 |    0     |
> | 225 | 2017-09-26 03:24:14 |    0     |
> | 226 | 2017-09-26 03:33:00 |    0     |
> | 227 | 2017-09-26 20:47:00 |    0     |
> | 228 | 2017-09-27 12:37:00 |    0     |
> | 229 | 2017-09-27 15:14:00 |    0     |
> +-----+---------------------+----------+
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vc não poderia executar uma unica consulta pra retornar os dois valores q vc quer, em vez de ter q fazer duas consultas e todos esses calculos??

Algo assim não resolveria seu problema:

`SELECT * FROM roexd_content WHERE featured=0 ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 0,2;`

Dessa forma vc ordena as datas por ordem decrescente, busca apenas por featured que estão como 0, e limita para 2 unicos resultados. 
Assim retorna o ultimo e o penultimo registro q vc desja de uma só vez.

Comment: Agradeço sua atenção e realmente uma visão simplificada do problema, fiquei envolvido pelo que o cliente estava precisando e pedindo, e não tive como observar a solução. Obrigado mais uma vez pelo seu tempo dispensado a minha pessoa, bom final de semana, meu amigo.

Comment: rsrs é as vezes a solução é tão simples que não percebemos rsrs, se isso resolveu seu problema, só peço para que sinalize a resposta como escolhida e de um votinho pra cima para ajudar o amigo aqui kkk
Abraços e bom fim de semana pra vc tbm.